# Google Maps in Typescript or Angular 2

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript

How can I use Google Maps Javascript API in Typescript or actually in Angular 2?

Yes, there are libraries like https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps there which I can use but they don't have complete support like Events and Places Libraries or Ground Overlays(or maybe I can find a way from the documentation)

So, is there I can directly access library from Google only as its latest version at all times, also has all the functionalities?

If, it ain't possible is there some way I can import some Javascript or some other work around?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just import it into your project. If you use webpack, look up how to add external libraries. If you are using the angular-cli, just add the JavaScript file to the list of scripts in the angular-cli.json. Once you do that, just declare it on top of the component where you want to use it, with:

```
const google: any;
```

And then you can call all the methods to do use the actual library.

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal run the following command to add the google map library

`npm install @types/googlemaps --save`

Add your api key into index.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

Finally insert imports into module.ts

```
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
```

Now you can create google map using

`new google.maps.Map(<htmlElement>, mapOptions());`

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, run the following command to add the library:

```
npm install @types/googlemaps --save
```

Then in */src/typings.d.ts* insert the following line to the list of imports:

```
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
```